# Machine learning dataframe

Tags: machine-learning

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import datasets, linear_model

diabetes=datasets.load_diabetes(as_frame=True)
df=pd.DataFrame(diabetes)
print(df)
```

I want to show diabetes data to dataframe, how we can do it

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(diabetes['data'], columns=diabetes['feature_names'])
df['target'] = diabetes['target']

print(df.head())
        age       sex       bmi        bp        s1        s2        s3        s4        s5        s6  target
0  0.038076  0.050680  0.061696  0.021872 -0.044223 -0.034821 -0.043401 -0.002592  0.019908 -0.017646   151.0
1 -0.001882 -0.044642 -0.051474 -0.026328 -0.008449 -0.019163  0.074412 -0.039493 -0.068330 -0.092204    75.0
2  0.085299  0.050680  0.044451 -0.005671 -0.045599 -0.034194 -0.032356 -0.002592  0.002864 -0.025930   141.0
3 -0.089063 -0.044642 -0.011595 -0.036656  0.012191  0.024991 -0.036038  0.034309  0.022692 -0.009362   206.0
4  0.005383 -0.044642 -0.036385  0.021872  0.003935  0.015596  0.008142 -0.002592 -0.031991 -0.046641   135.0
```